# Getting unique couples with nan

Tags: python, numpy, unique, nan

**Want I want to achieve**

I wish to get unique rows in a 2d numpy array containing nan.

More generally I would like to obtain unique values according to an axis in a n-d `numpy.ndarray`.

**A reproducible example**

```
import numpy as np
example = np.array([[0, np.nan], 
                    [np.nan, 1], 
                    [0, np.nan], 
                    [np.nan, np.nan], 
                    [np.nan, 1], 
                    [np.nan, np.nan]])
```

What I wish as a result it:

```
array([[ 0., nan],
       [nan,  1.],
       [nan, nan]])
```

**What I have try**

I have tried using `np.unique` but it won't work:

```
np.unique(example, axis=0)
```

Result is:

```
array([[ 0., nan],
       [ 0., nan],
       [nan,  1.],
       [nan,  1.],
       [nan, nan],
       [nan, nan]])
```

So I have discovered that `np.nan == np.nan` is `False` ... :/

I have thought of using `np.allclose` which as an `equal_nan` option. But re-implementing unique will not be efficient

**NB:** I want to use it in a large scale way. So it should be fast.

Does any function exist? Have I to code it? Any advice would be helpful.

Comment: You might find helpful ideas and proposed patches in this [bug report](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/2111).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `pandas.DataFrame` for that. Pandas builds on top of numpy 2d-arrays and you get the bare array if you get the `values` attribute of a DataFrame.
To just keep unique rows use `drop_duplicates`:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.DataFrame(example).drop_duplicates().values
# Out: 
array([[ 0., nan],
       [nan,  1.],
       [nan, nan]])
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace `nan` with any value that is certainly not in the data, and `np.unique` will just work:

```
import numpy as np
example = np.array([[0, np.nan], 
                    [np.nan, 1], 
                    [0, np.nan], 
                    [np.nan, np.nan], 
                    [np.nan, 1], 
                    [np.nan, np.nan]])

# substitute nan with inf
example[np.isnan(example)] = np.inf

u = np.unique(example, axis=0)

# substitute inf with nan
u[u == np.inf] = np.nan

print(u)
# [[  0.  nan]
#  [ nan   1.]
#  [ nan  nan]]
```

In the example I used `inf` but any other value is fine. Just make sure it cannot occur in the data.

Comment: Yup, thought of that also, but i found it a bit ugly. + Will not work with say string

Comment: @Emmanuel-Lin I agree, it is a bit ugly - but so are NANs :) String and NAN is a strange combination. If you use strings anyway there is no real need for "not a number" values that are not strings themselves.

Comment: yes you are right regarding strings; okay. 
I leave the question open for a bit more time to see if someone as a "cleaner" idea and if not i will accept yours

Comment: No worries. Take your time and accept whichever answer works best for you. (Darkonaut's answer looks like a good candidate if you consider Pandas a clean solution.)